# ExtJS 3.2.1 GroupingStore.js sort method

Tags: extjs

Anyone experience problems utilizing the sort method in the GroupingStore.js file of ExtJS 3.2.1?   I have over 2000 records to load in a grid control and I get long running script notices.   It goes away and continues processing.

I know there is a registry fix published by MS to fix this, but I'd rather resolve it with coding if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoa, 2000 records without paging? And then you're trying to sort it?

I've always converted any grids that might possibly go over 500 records into paging grids with either the paging toolbar or paging scrollbar.

In my experience, anything much beyond that weighs too heavy on client resources to justify any intuitive use benefits gained from not having these. 2000 would definitely warrant paging I think, that would handle your long running script problems.

I don't thing ExtJS3 had built in paging scrollbar, there might be a ux for it though. It does have paging toolbar though, [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.PagingToolbar).

You should implement back end sorting, then that toolbar will request the data in smaller chunks (pages) as covered in the doc link above.